# How to have a smooth edges after rotating the UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, smoothing

I am rotating a view by some angle by after rotating I am not getting the smooth edge of the view. Please check the attached image. Is there any way to have a smooth edge of UIView?

I have used the following statement for this purpose.

```
CGContextRotateCTM(currentContext, RADIANS(-5));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It helps a lot if you set `shouldRasterize = true` for the layer of your view.

```
yourView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

> When the value of this property is true, the layer is rendered as a
>   bitmap in its local coordinate space and then composited to the
>   destination with any other content. Shadow effects and any filters in
>   the filters property are rasterized and included in the bitmap.
>   However, the current opacity of the layer is not rasterized. If the
>   rasterized bitmap requires scaling during compositing, the filters in
>   the minificationFilter and magnificationFilter properties are applied
>   as needed.

Comment: This only applies to transforms applied to layers. OP is using Quartz (CoreGraphics) drawing.

Comment: this is indeed the usual solution, when you do something like **whitePanel.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: -d )**

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling anti-aliasing before rotating:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(currentContext, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

set 1 pixel transparent border. This will helps you magically.

Comment: Add and import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
Suppose your view is cv
now use
cv.layer.borderWidth = 1;//border width in pixel
cv.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;